# Javascript: Memory efficient way to do this effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote the code in Javascript but any good alternative would do.

EFFECT: onmousemove over the webpage circles of random colors should create wherever the mouse moves. and they have to be added behind a mask image(circles are visible only in the transparent portion of the image which is a logo. thus creating a color paint to create logo onmousemove.

it doesn't work in jsfidde because of its memory intensiveness.

WORKING LINK: http://goo.gl/DNRxO9

I pasted the exact code you can create a new html file with the following code and IT WORKS PERFECT IN FIREFOX ONLY because of its memory intensiveness(lots of divs added in very short time so DOM becomes very very heavy).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow: hidden;

}
#mask{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
}
#logo{
width:50%;
height:50%;
margin:auto;
}
.point{
width:0px;
height:0px;
background-color:#ff0000;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
left:50px;top:50px;
border-width:50px;
border-style: solid;
border-color:red;
border-radius:50px;
opacity:1;
transition: border-width 3s ease-in-out;
}
.no-border{border-width:0px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

/* OptionalCode: for removing divs after a lot are created */
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}

i=0;
function colors(event){
    var x=event.clientX;
    var y=event.clientY;
    var point = document.getElementsByClassName('point');
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='point'></div>";
    point[i].style.borderColor = getRandomColor();
    //point[i].className += ' no-border';
    point[i].style.left = x + 'px';
    point[i].style.top = y + 'px';
    i++;
}
function position(){
    var ht = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("mask"), null).getPropertyValue("height");
    var ht_num = Number(ht.slice(0,ht.length - 2));
    margin_top = (Number(document.body.clientHeight) - ht_num)/2;
    document.getElementById('mask').style.marginTop = margin_top + "px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="position();" onmousemove="colors(event)">
<img id="mask" src="http://goo.gl/EqfJ0L">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one *HUGE, HUGE, HUGE* performance killer in your code:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='point'></div>";
```

This takes your *entire document, throws it away and just inserts everything back again*. This is horrible! Remember this for all times and never do this again! ;)

Keep the basic rule in mind, to never add Elements via `.innerHTML`!

The correct way to go is the following:

```
// create your new div element
var circleElement = document.createElement("div");
// add all the stuff needed
circleElement.classList.add("point");
circleElement.style.borderColor = getRandomColor();
circleElement.style.left = x + 'px';
circleElement.style.top = y + 'px';
// now append the element to the body
document.body.appendChild(circleElement);
```

This creates a single div and nicely inserts it as a child-element of the body.

Additionally you can decrease the number of divs drawn by introducing a threshhold:

```
var lastX=0,lastY=0;
function colors(event){
    var x=event.clientX;
    var y=event.clientY;
    if (Math.abs(lastX - x) + Math.abs(lastY - y) <= 10 ) return;
    /* do stuff */
    lastX = x;lastY = y;
}
```

As a third measure you can decrease the size of the image to just hold the mask element and trigger the mousemove only on the image (because divs outside the mask are hidden anyway).

Ultimately, you could kill "old" div-elements when you have reached a certain amount.

I have not included these two last optimizations, but look at the already [supersmooth example now](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/3N4qn/)!